# How to input text Value renders as html entity in Vue. some stuffs i check and not solved area

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.1

[See Image for discription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEZCG.png) Discription is in image its all about the input form  value not persist properly in vue it shows Unicode

Comment: what is your mean when you say not working? you can see see this example for vuejs that it works perfect : https://jsbin.com/zimipocosu/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use interpolation inside html tags. Go for `v-bind:value`:

```
<input type="text" name="check" v-bind:value="item.name"></input>
```

Also you are opening an `input`, but closing with `span`